# Input validation for Number (user cant input less than 163)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to restrict user from giving value less than 163. 
I already tried

```
<input type="text" class="inputnw" name="semesterCode" min="163" value="163" />
```

I have used text as i dont want to show increment/decrement at the right side of input box.

I want validation for anything below 163 and User can only type numeric number.

Comment: You should change type to number from text.<input type="number" class="inputnw" name="semesterCode" min="163" value="163" />

Comment: Use type number and its very basic you can check from : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_min.asp

Comment: You might add a listener for the *blur* or *input* events that provides a message if the value is less than 163, such as `if (this.value < 163) /* show message */`. Don't delete the user input, let them fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this script. Whenever you enter a number less than 163 it will give an alert saying "Number must be less than 163"

```js
function myFunction(){
  var x = document.getElementById("number").value;
  if ( x.length > 2 && x < 163 ) {
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Please enter a number less than 163"
    return false 
  }else{
    return true
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="number" class="inputnw" name="semesterCode"  onkeyup="myFunction()"/>
<span id="error" style="color:red"></span>
```

Comment: working . Want input box error in replace of "alert" .what should i do? @shubham

Answer (score 0):

Use below Jquery code (Remember i assumed you are using Jquery), Just apply this class "inputnw" for fields you want do this kind of validation.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('keypress keyup blur', '.inputnw', function (event) {
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, ''));
        // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
        if ($.inArray(event.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
            // Allow: Ctrl+A
            (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) ||
            // Allow: home, end, left, right
            (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) {
            // let it happen, don't do anything
            return;
        }

        if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }

        if ($(this).val().length >= 3) {
            if ($(this).val() < 163) {
                $(this).val('');
                alert('Please enter value greater than 163');
                $(this).focus();
            }
        }
    });

    $('.inputnw').blur(function () {
        if ($(this).val().length < 3) {
            if ($(this).val() < 163) {
                $(this).val('');
                alert('Please enter value greater than 163');
                $(this).focus();
            }
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: It is very inefficient to repeat `$(this)` many times, do it once and assign the result to a variable. Also, it's inefficient and unreliable to check key strokes, what if the user pastes a value, or drags and drops a value? Just test the value.

Answer (score 0):

Use `type=number` for the input field! it is really feasible and effective and use the following style to disable the arrows for the input box

```
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}
input[type="number"] {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

Sample Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/LaApGngTkJL14mmTmi78?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can add a listener to check the value based on some event. Let the user fix the value themselves and make the message user friendly:

```js
function checkValue(){
  var errorEl = document.getElementById(this.id + 'Error');
  var message = 'Value must be ' + this.dataset.min + ' or greater';
  if (errorEl) {
    errorEl.textContent = +this.value >= +this.dataset.min? '' : message;
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  var el = document.getElementById('semesterCode');
  el.addEventListener('input', checkValue, false);
}
```

```css
.errorMessage {
  color: red;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 80%;
}
```

```html
<input name="semesterCode" id="semesterCode" data-min="163" value="163"><br>
<span id="semesterCodeError" class="errorMessage">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change the type to number and do something like this using the validity object of the input object

```html
<input type="number" class="inputnw" name="semesterCode" min="163" onblur="if(this.validity.rangeUnderflow)this.setCustomValidity('I expect 163');" />
```